# gdb step back and forth with the next command over gcc compiled C++ program

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, libtool

my gcc compiler is provided by ubuntu:
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

gdb is vesion 7.11.1

The binary was build with littools.

When stepping a simple test C++ program with only a few lines, it will go back and forth, eventually it will step to the end.  If you execute the binary, it has no problem of executing it.  I wonder, whether it is a bug of my compiler or gdb?  This problem maybe very rare.  My ubuntu is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.  kernel: 4.4.0-128-generic.  I had never had problems before with stepping through programs before. The current gdb can use the continue command finish the program without any issues.

```
gdb /usr/local/bin/testrepeatrun
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/testrepeatrun...done.
(gdb) b 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4018f4: file testrepeatrun.cpp, line 9.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/testrepeatrun 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd68) at testrepeatrun.cpp:9
9      string sA1 = "ACCCGTGTGGCCAGTCGTACGTGTACACTGACGTACGATCAGTC";
(gdb) next
8   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
(gdb) n
9      string sA1 = "ACCCGTGTGGCCAGTCGTACGTGTACACTGACGTACGATCAGTC";
(gdb) n
8   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
```

My problem is going backward with next.  9 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 ...
15 -> 17 -> 15 -> 17 repeated at least twice then go to the next line.

Comment: Did you compile with optimization enabled?

Comment: gdb does pretty good to display the line of code next to execute.  With higher optimizations, the compiler can re-arrange the code to achieve various goals (performance, size, etc).  Compiling with -O0 will reduce the code rearrangement, and thus reduce the 'back-and-forth' so that gdb stepping will make more sense.

Comment: I thought it was a bug, updated compiler to 7.x, gdb to 8x still the same problem.  I used the default -o2 -g flag.  I am glad there is already an answer to this problem.  I did a lots of search and did not find any posting for this issue.

Comment: Export CXXFLAGS=-g then ./configure solved my problem.